# Unable to create entry in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, join, cocoon-gem

I'm attempting to save an entry to a join table, but have been unsuccessful.  As I have it configured, `Stockholder` `has_many :entity_joins` (I'm attempting to allow a `Stockholder` to consist of multiple `people` and to allow a `Person` to participate with multiple `stockholders`.  Each join entry for a single stockholder is added with cocoon as follows:

```
<h1>Stockholders#edit</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/stockholders/edit.html.erb</p>
<%=  simple_form_for [@stock, @stockholder], html: {id:"stockholderform"}, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |f| %>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="symegrid">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <%= simple_fields_for :entity_joins do |ejoin| %>
                    <%= render 'entity_join_fields', f:ejoin %>
                <% end %>
                <div>
                    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Owner', f, :entity_joins, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
                </div>
```

The entity_join_fields just consist of a single field to indicate which person should be added to the `Stockholder` via a select menu:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :entity_id, [Org, Person], :all, :model_name, :to_global_id, lambda {|org_or_person_object| org_or_person_object.instance_of? Org? rescue org_or_person_object.fname + " " + org_or_person_object.lname rescue org_or_person_object.name}, label:"Stockholder", class: "names"%>
```

But when I go to save the `Stockholder` form, the parameters in the development.log are as follows:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JF6a/hVU49y1AAX4iAyi6t/Y/ti1S6CAotw28Qj8PGbESpl/puMUliqOz9iwUQ9vHwIeF5hFjykwSUTcKpzGrQ==", "entity_joins"=>{"entity_id"=>"gid://legal/Person/2"}, "stockholder"=>{"cert_number"=>"", "issue_date(2i)"=>"12", "issue_date(3i)"=>"2", "issue_date(1i)"=>"2015", "shares_issued"=>"", "shares_repurchased"=>"", "shares_canceled"=>"", "shares_outstanding"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Stockholder", "stock_id"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}
```

The most striking thing about it is that `entity_joins` falls outside of `stockholder` params and is not nested within it.  Obviously, it isn't saving to the database and no errors are being thrown either.  The data for `entity_joins` is correct (it's the global id for the `Person` so that I might be able to expand the join to be polymorphic but that's another story).  Is there anything obvious that might be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `simple_fields_for` on the form builder instance:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :entity_joins do |ejoin| %>
  <%= render 'entity_join_fields', f:ejoin %>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise it does not have a context and will just create inputs with `name="entity_joins[something]"` instead of `stockholder[entity_joins][something]`.

Comment: HAH!  Oh boy, I think that's a sign that it's time for me to go to sleep.  Thanks so much. :-P